# How to return data from forkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am new to rxjs and I'm having a problem using forkJoin.

I have an angular service that asks two other angular services for data and returns that combined data to a component.

But when I call that service using the following code snippet within my angular component, I don't get all the data:

```
this.timeseriesKpiData = this.timeseriesKpiDataService
      .getLatestTimeseriesKpi(this.assetId, this.aspectName, this.variableName,
```

Here is the method I'm calling within my service:

timeseriesKpiDataService.ts:

```
 public getLatestTimeseriesKpi(
    assetId: string,
    aspectName: string,
    variableName: string
  ): any {

    const timeseriesKpiData = {
      name: '',
      value: 'no value found',
      unit: '',
      properties: [
        {
          name: 'Asset',
          value: 'Unknown Asset'
        }
      ]
    };

    // set variableName and aspectName
    timeseriesKpiData.name = variableName;
    timeseriesKpiData.properties.concat( {
      name: 'Aspect',
      value: aspectName} );

    forkJoin (
      // get latest timeseries from another service
      this.timeseriesService.getLatestTimeseriesValue(assetId, aspectName)
        .pipe(
          map((latestTimeseries: Timeseries) => {
            return latestTimeseries;
          }
        )),

      // get unit
      this.aspectService.getUnit(assetId, aspectName)
        .pipe(
          map((unit: any) => {
            return unit;
          })
      )).subscribe(([latestTimeseries, unit]) => {
        if (latestTimeseries !== undefined) {

          // set value
          timeseriesKpiData.value = latestTimeseries[timeseriesKpiData.name];

          // set unit
          timeseriesKpiData.unit = unit;
       }
      }
      });  // end of forkjoin

      return timeseriesKpiData; // how to return it?
    }
```

I think the problem is the forkjoin and that it is still running when I return my data to the component and thus I don't get all the required data (the timeseriesKpiData.value is not set).

So my question is, how can I return data from forkjoin, or wait somehow for forkjoin to end before I return data to my component?

Comment: That's exactly what you're saying. Instead, return the forkJoin and in your component, subscribe to it.

Comment: Please, not subscribe in service, if you want to store the result in a variable of service use pipe(tap(res=>{this.variable=res})). Normally you use the variable of subscribe, but "tap" is just after subscribe. So, in your component when subscribe in subscription you're sure the variable is in the service, see a fool example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3deuqh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should return `forkjoin` instead so your code should look like

```
public getLatestTimeseriesKpi(
    assetId: string,
    aspectName: string,
    variableName: string
  ): any {

    const timeseriesKpiData = {
      name: '',
      value: 'no value found',
      unit: '',
      properties: [
        {
          name: 'Asset',
          value: 'Unknown Asset'
        }
      ]
    };

    // set variableName and aspectName
    timeseriesKpiData.name = variableName;
    timeseriesKpiData.properties.concat( {
      name: 'Aspect',
      value: aspectName} );

   return forkJoin (
      // get latest timeseries from another service
      this.timeseriesService.getLatestTimeseriesValue(assetId, aspectName),

      // get unit
      this.aspectService.getUnit(assetId, aspectName));  // end of forkjoin
    }
```

then in your component

```
this.timeseriesKpiDataService
      .getLatestTimeseriesKpi(this.assetId, this.aspectName, this.variableName).subscribe(([latestTimeseries, unit]) => {
        if (latestTimeseries !== undefined) {
         this.timeseriesKpiData:any ={};
          // set value
          this.timeseriesKpiData.value = latestTimeseries[timeseriesKpiData.name];

          // set unit
          this.timeseriesKpiData.unit = unit;

       }
      }
  })
```